# Convert word document to PDF in SharePoint 2013 Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

Hello friend i created one Visual Web Part Sandbox Solution for converting word document into PDF and store it into File Explorer.
So i add a reference of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Version 15.0.0.0 to my solution.
Below code is for design file.

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var uploadcontrol = document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>').value;
        var reg = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(w[\w].*))+(.doc| .docx | .DOC |.DOCX)$/;
        if (uploadcontrol.length > 0)
        {
            if (reg.test(uploadcontrol)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Only .doc,docx files are allowed!");
                uploadcontrol.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('Please Select a file to Upload');
            uploadcontrol.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="27px" Text="Upload"
        width="122px" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return validate();" />
</p>
```

Here i take one Control for File Upload so client can upload .doc or .docx file and when it click on Upload button word file will convert into PDF and stored in his local Machine which is right now Hard Code.In Visual Studio Solution Build and Deploy successfully.
I have created one WepPart Page and add the custome web part in page,Now when client Upload Word Document and click on Upload Button then got Below Error.

**"ConvertToPDF - VisualWebPart1
Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application' from assembly 'ConvertToPDF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ee035cf3e0b5c7ba'. The type is marked as eligible for type equivalence, but the containing assembly is not loaded as fully trusted. Correlation ID: 989aa09c-e86e-d0df-a6bb-4f3c556079a9. "**

Below is the code of

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
            { 
                // Create a new Microsoft Word application object
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

                // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
                object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                // Get a Word file
                FileInfo wordFile = new FileInfo("D:\\Projects\\mydoc.doc");


                word.Visible = false;
                word.ScreenUpdating = false;

                // Cast as Object for word Open method
                Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

                // Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
                Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc.Activate();
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(wordFile.FullName);
                object outputFileName = new object();
                if (ext == "doc")
                {
                    outputFileName = "D:\\WPF\\DemoApp\\WordToExcel\\demo.pdf";

                }
                else
                {
                    outputFileName = "D:\\WPF\\DemoApp\\WordToExcel\\demo.pdf";
                }


                object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

                // Save document into PDF Format

                doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                    ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

               // string destUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + DocumentLibName + outputFileName;


                // Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
                // doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the
                // correct Close method.                
                object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc = null;

                // word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find
                // the correct Quit method.
                ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                word = null;  

    }

}
```

Note: I have also create Console Application and that's work fine and giving Correct Result means i can convert Word to PDF using this but only getting error in SharePoint.

Any help is highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your PDF assembly and the MS Interop assemblies to the SafeControls collection.

Comment: try running a console application on the server then, instead of opening the MS interop in the SP sandbox. I don't know if you can do this or if it will help, but you may just as well try it.

Comment: i have one doubt "Is it compulsory that for used this services or assembly Microsoft Office have to be installed in server" if yes than how can i do this with Office 365 we don't have any server access.